# Does Python3 short-circuit on list comparison?

Tags: python-3.x

Given to same-length but different lists `a` and `b`, when performing `a == b` will Python iterate through both entire lists, or will it stop on first inequality?

Comment: what purpose would iterating further have? just curious...

Comment: It stops as soon as it can. It's basically `(a is b) or ((len(a) == len(b)) and all(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)))`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I'm testing whether one can infer the contents of a list by guessing its content and measuring the time it takes to compae two lists... So continuing would obscure that piece of information.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it seems that comparison with == is much faster than just using the 'any' clause in your code... Is there any other mechanism at play?

Comment: That's just the Python equivalent, the actual comparison is carried out at the C level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got this question, you can simply test it:

```
a = [9] + list(range(2000))
b = [8] + list(range(2000))

def diff_at_start(): 
    return a == b

aa = list(range(2000)) + [9]
bb = list(range(2000)) + [8]

def diff_at_end(): 
    return aa == bb

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit

    print(timeit.timeit("diff_at_start()", 
          setup="from __main__ import diff_at_start",
          number=1000))

    print(timeit.timeit("diff_at_end()", 
          setup="from __main__ import diff_at_end", 
          number=1000))
```

Output:

```
0.000169038772583  # diff_at_start
0.0287721157074    # diff_at_end
```

showing that in fact, a difference at the begin of a list, shortens the execution time considerably.

See

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html